# Inserir vários checkboxs no Banco de Dados

Tags: php

Como insiro vários checkbox na mesma linha do banco de dados?

Segue o código, o checkbox **menu** é o que será inserido várias vezes:

```
require_once("conn.php");

$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
$menu=$_POST['menu'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `portfolio` (`nome`, `tipo`, `desc`, `menu`)
 VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$tipo."', '".$desc."', '".$menu."')";

// Executa a query
$inserir = mysql_query($query);

if ($inserir) {
echo "Post inserido com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível inserir o Post, tente novamente.";
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:
echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysql_error();
}
```

FORM:

```
 <form action="recebe.php" method="POST">
         <label>NOME DO CLIENTE:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" style="
    margin-left: 50px;
"><br><br />
         <label>TIPO DE SERVIÇO</label>
            <input type="text" name="tipo" style="
    margin-left: 57px;
"><br><br />
         <label>MENU:</label>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="visu," value="visu,"><label for="visu,">IDENTIDADE VISUAL</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="web," value="web,"><label for="web,">DESENVOLVIMENTO WEB</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="grafico,tdmg," value="grafico,tdmg,"><label for="grafico,tdmg,">MATERIAL GRAFICO</label><br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="visimg," value="visimg," class="radiosaq"><label for="visimg,">CARTÃO DE VISITA</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="pap," value="pap," class="radiosaq"><label for="pap,">PAPELARIA</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="fol," value="fol," class="radiosaq"><label for="fol,">FOLDER</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="card," value="card," class="radiosaq"><label for="card,">CARDÁPIO</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="rev," value="rev," class="radiosaq"><label for="rev,">REVISTA</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="emb," value="emb," class="radiosaq"><label for="emb,">EMBALAGEM</label><br>


        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="comu,tdcv," value="comu,tdcv,"><label for="comu,tdcv,">COMUNICAÇÃO VISUAL</label><br>

             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="amb," value="amb," class="radiosaq"><label for="amb,">AMBIENTAÇÃO</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="dec," value="dec," class="radiosaq"><label for="dec,">DECORAÇÃO</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="ade," value="ade," class="radiosaq"><label for="ade,">ADESIVOS</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="pla," value="pla," class="radiosaq"><label for="pla,">PLACAS</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="ban," value="ban," class="radiosaq"><label for="ban,">BANNERS</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="plo," value="plo," class="radiosaq"><label for="plo,">PLOTAGEM</label><br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="out," value="out," class="radiosaq"><label for="out,">OUTROS</label><br>


        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="digi," value="digi,"><label for="digi,">MARKETING DIGITAL</label><br>
  </fieldset><br /><br />
         <label>IMAGEM MINI:</label>  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"><br><br />
         <label>IMAGEM GRANDE:</label>  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"><br><br />
       <label>DESCRIÇÃO</label><br />
           <textarea id="desc" name="desc" required=""></textarea><br><br />
     <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR DADOS PARA O SITE :D">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você atualizou a pergunta, segue uma pequena correção. Tem que tirar as vírgulas dos valores, pois o `implode` já vai colocá-las, e o `name` precisa ser ajustado:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" id="visimg" value="visimg" class="radiosaq">
```

Neste caso, em especial, você pode deixar uma vírgula separando os ítens, só sugeriria não usar vírgula no ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" id="grafico_tdmg" value="grafico,tdmg">
```

Depois, é basicamente isto:

```
$menu = isset( $_POST['menu'] ) && is_array( $_POST['menu'] )
        ? implode( ',', $_POST['menu'] ) : '';
```

Só pra ficar mais legível:

```
if( isset( $_POST['menu'] ) && is_array( $_POST['menu'] ) ) {
   $menu = implode( ',', $_POST['menu'] );
} else {
   $menu = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que quer não é recomendado (pois fere a 1FN).

Pois bem, o $_POST['menu'] contém as duas  informações de valor 1 e valor 2, caso ambos sejam marcados.

O que pode fazer para inserir ambos os valores no banco de dados em uma única coluna é:

**1. Serialize:**

```
$menu = serialize($_POST['menu']);    
// irá gerar um valor armazenável, tornando a array como está em uma string.
```

Para recuperar os dados utilize o `unserialize()`, irá voltar a array, do jeito que estava.

**2. Implode (mencionado acima):**

```
$menu = implode(',',$_POST['menu']);
// irá inserir virgula (ou outro elemento que desejar) entre cada item.
```

Para recuperar os dados utilize `explode()`, assim irá retornar como estava.

**Nota:**

> Não foi levado  em consideração nenhum recurso de segurança, inclusive o mysql_query já está obsoleto.
>
> Armazenamento deste tipo não é recomendado. O ideal é crie outra tabela para armazenar estas informações e depois efetue um `JOIN` ou `IN` para obter os dados de duas tabelas.